# how to achieve a collated summary report when jmeter is being run in distributed mode

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, distributed, group

I have made a distributed set up for jmeter (1 master + 2 slaves), I have kept thread count 50 in master machine's Jmeter UI and hoping that both the slaves will also send 50-50 request each (as slaves replicate the script of master), combining the total hits at the server as 150 requests. but i am getting summary report of only 50 users at the end of the test. I want to see the total 150 hits to the server where each machine is sending 50 requests.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter master neither executes any requests nor starts any threads, if you have 2 slaves and want to kick off 150 threads in total you should put 75 threads in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) in the master.

Also don't use GUI for running tests, it's only for development and debugging, [you should execute your JMeter scenario in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)

```
jmeter -Rslave1,slave2 -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

if you want the master to also send the requests you need to launch jmeter-server process on master node as well and tell JMeter to use master machine:

```
jmeter -Rslave1,slave2,localhost -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

More information:

- [Remote Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
- [Apache JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)

Comment: I have given 75 threads in the thread group of master m/c without using the master to send any requests, where i am expecting both the slave should execute 75 request each.but i am getting the summary report of only 75 request instead of 150.i want to see a report of 150 requests